# Обновления данных на странице после изменения, ajax, как обновлять проверку if?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

На странице у меня проверка, если значение в поле в таблице 0, то выводим кнопку, если 1, то скрываем, так вот после того как я нажал на кнопку вернуть деньги, у меня идет запись в таблицу в бд, вместо 0, я записываю 1, и я пытаюсь обновить данную проверку, чтобы скрыть кнопку, ибо значение уже перезаписалось в таблице, следовательно надо как-то обновить но не всю страницу, а только проверку, ниже изложил чтобы понятно было.

```
<?php if (empty($order->refunded)) : ?>
<form id="backM" action="/admin/backM/<?= $id ?>" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="backM" value="1">

<button type="submit">Вернуть деньги</button>

<div class="message-backM"></div>
</form>
<?php endif; ?>
```

**Валидация и т.д**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $(document).on('submit', '#backM', function(event) {
      $('#backM .message-backM').html('');
      let form = this;
      event.preventDefault();
      let formLoad = new FormData($(form)[0]);
      formLoad.append('ajax', 1);
      $.ajax({
        url: $(this).attr('action'),
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: formLoad,
        beforeSend: function() {
          App.showLoader();
        },
        complete: function() {
          App.hideLoader();
        },
        success: function(d) {
          if (d.status == 'success') {

            //пытаюсь обновить проверку if, чтобы скрыть кнопку
            **$('#refunded').text(d.data.refunded);**

            App.hideLoader();
            App.bootstrap.addAlert('#backM .message-backM', 'success', d.message);
          }
          if (d.status == 'error') {
            App.bootstrap.addAlert('#backM .message-backM', 'error', d.message);
          }
          App.hideLoader();
        },
        error: function() {
          App.hideLoader();
          App.bootstrap.addAlert('#backM .message-backM', 'error', e.message);
        },
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false
      });
    });
  });
```

**Контроллер**

```
public function action_backM()
  {
    $_isAjax = Arr::get($_POST, 'ajax', 1);
    $id = (int)$this->request->param('id');
    $orders = ORM::factory('Order', $id);

    if (!empty($_isAjax)) {
      $data = Arr::extract(
        $_POST,
        array(
          'backM'
        )
      );

      $orders->values($data);

      try {

        $orders->set('refunded', $data['backM']);
        $orders->save();

        /* отправляю новые данные после изменения */
         $_data = array(
          'refunded' => $orders->refunded,
        );

        die(json_encode([
          'status' => 'success',
          'data' => $_data,
          'message' => 'Вы успешно сделали возврат денег.'
        ], JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE));
      } catch (Exception $e) {
        die(json_encode([
          'status' => 'error',
          'title' => 'Произошла ошибка, попробуйте повторить действия позже.',
          'message' => $e->getMessage()
        ], JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE));
      }
    }
  }
```

Вообщем в контролере я собираю новые данные после изменения и отправляю ajax

```
$_data = array(
'refunded' => $orders->refunded,
);
```

Далее в js, я их получаю и вывожу

```
$('#refunded').text(d.data.refunded);
```

Работает выводит цифру 1, все верно.

**Но мне не совсем это надо, мне не выводить надо цифру, а как-то в проверку подставлять (проверка ниже if (empty($order->refunded)), что уже не 0, а 1, как сделать?**

```
<?php if (empty($order->refunded)) : ?>
тут кнопка
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вообщем, не хотел я делать так но сделал по простому, просто прячу кнопку и надписи при результате success. $('.backHide').remove(); все гениальное просто ), нам же временно визуально надо спрятать, ну что типа произошли в реальном времени изменения. чтоб не обновлять всю страницу полностью.